# DB Error: no such table

Tags: wordpress

I am using CIVICRM imported from a Drupal installation now in wordpress.

The entire import process was done according to the corresponding tutorials.

Everything works fine, except when trying to see the detail of a member through the list of members. The following error appears:
DB Error: no such table

Next I copy the result of the backtrace

I am a new user of CIVICRM, I saw similar topics in the forum but I do not understand where the error may be.

I already appreciate the help you can give me. Excuse my English, it has been translated from Spanish automatically.

```
#0 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n ...")
#3 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n ...")
#4 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, "SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n ...", "1146 ** Table 'andrcdd_wpcivic3.civicrm_worldregion' doesn't exist")
#7 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n")
#9 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n")
#10 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(413): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT  id, name  \n FROM civicrm_worldregion \n \n \n \n \n ORDER BY id  \n")
#11 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php(571): DB_DataObject->find()
#12 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php(1202): CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::populate(NULL, "CRM_Core_DAO_Worldregion", TRUE, "name", NULL, NULL, "id")
#13 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(527): CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::worldRegion("2")
#14 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Location.php(267): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::getValues((Array:1), TRUE)
#15 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(851): CRM_Core_BAO_Location::getValues((Array:1), TRUE)
#16 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(138): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::retrieve((Array:4), (Array:31), TRUE)
#17 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(93): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->view()
#18 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run((Array:3), NULL)
#19 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#20 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#21 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1243): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#22 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#23 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#24 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#25 /home3/andrcdd/public_html/nueva/wp-admin/admin.php(253): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

Comment: The database table `civicrm_worldregion` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your table world_region is not imported correctly. You could check in your new database whether that table exists.

Comment: Thank you! Effectively, that table had not been imported. You create it as it existed in the previous database and the problem has been solved. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I have this same issue that the table did not import,
However, Whenever trying to import this table I am getting ```#1005 - Can't create table `DB_NAME`.`civicrm_worldregion` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)```
Any ideas for what I can do?